# Setting up PSQL for use with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, psql, pg

I've been trying to set up my new macbook pro (Sierra 10.12.5) for using Rails - I've installed Ruby 2.4.1, Rails 5.0.2 and PSQL 9.6.3. I was having trouble over installing pg 0.20.0, but I was able to do this through Homebrew.

Now I'm unable to run any of my MVCs through the local host as I'm told:

```
PG Connection Bad - fe_sendauth: no password supplied -
    # connected server's characteristics.
    def connect
      @connection = PGconn.connect(@connection_parameters)
      configure_connection
    rescue ::PG::Error => error
      if error.message.include?("does not exist")
```

I assume this to be a problem with psql connecting to the server, but I'm really not sure what it could be or what to do next.

I would really appreciate any pointers, thanks.

Comment: did you configured database.yml properly ???

Comment: You need to set the configuration in database yml file. It seems you may have set the same but not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `config/database.yml` present with the following content

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: development_db
  pool: 5
  username: postgres # Replace this with correct username
  password: db_password # Replace this with correct password
  host: localhost
```

You can make use of Environment Variables here

```
username: <%= ENV['DB_USER'] %>
password: <%= ENV['DB_PASS'] %>
```

You need to set it first in shell

```
$ export DB_USER=postgres
$ export DB_PASS=password
```

Comment: Agreed, and it would be wide to look into gems that help manage those environment variables for you.

Comment: I guess the username and password were configured automatically when I set the MVC up as I don't remember anything about this.

Comment: However - I have a username and password for production only - development and test are left blank. I tried copying over the username and password from production, but this didn't work. Is there somewhere that I could find the username and password for development? Thanks

Comment: Sorry - to update - I do not have the db password and I have not yet set one. Where would I find this?

Comment: You can set one from postgres

Comment: default user is `postgres`

Comment: check how to change postgres password